# angular-ui datepicker directive

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm trying to make a directive to encapsulate and reuse the following angular-ui element:

```
<div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" data-ng-model="mv.dateReviewed" is-open="statusDateReviewed.opened" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
 <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDateReviewed($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </button>
 </span>
</div>
```

Surprised that [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started) components are called directives but are actually controllers (must be missing something here).

To summarize I've got 5 of those on a form and in 2 differents parts of my app, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
<date-picker data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" data-ng-model="oneWMS.dateReviewed" data-is-open="statusDateReviewed.opened" data-ng-click="openDateReviewed($event)"></date-picker>
```

And in my directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('datePicker',datePicker);

function datePicker() {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            format: '@format',
            ngModel: '@ngModel',
            isOpen: '@isOpen',
            ngClick: '@ngClick'

            },
        template: '<div class="input-group">' +
                 '<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" data-ng-model="oneWMS.dateReviewed" is-open="{{isOpen}}" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />' +
                 '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="{{ngClick}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </button>' +
                 '</span>' +
             '</div>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                // all the directive code
                console.log(iAttrs.format); // works
                console.log(iAttrs.ngModel); // works
                console.log(iAttrs.isOpen); // works
                console.log(iAttrs.ngClick); // works
```

The template works for the format but breaks with anything else (ngModel, isOpen, ngClick)

I get an error message

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{isOpen}}] starting at [{isOpen}}].
```

Any idea?

(PS: I would love to see someone use that angular-ui datepicker as a directive, with all the formatting...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems to work with:

```
scope: {
            format: '@',
            mod: '=ngModel',
            op: '=isOpen',
            cl: '=ngClick'

            },
        template: '<div class="input-group">' +
                 '<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" data-ng-model="mod" is-open="op" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />' +
                 '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cl"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </button>' +
                 '</span>' +
             '</div>',
```

But the directive is not working, I'm posting [a follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815551/making-angularui-datepicker-an-actual-directive) for that.