# Making AngularUI datepicker an actual directive

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to turn [angular-ui's date-picker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) into an actual directive.

I can display it on the page with the correct model and format, but the toggling doesn't work for me (trying to name it via the attributes).

Here is my code:
My html

```
<date-picker data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" data-model-name="dateReviewed" data-ng-model="oneWMS.dateReviewed" data-status="statusDateReviewed" data-opened="openDateReviewed"></date-picker>
```

My directive

```
function datePicker() {
          return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                format: '@',
                mod: '=ngModel',
                status: '@',
                opened: '@'

                },
            template: '<div class="input-group">' +
                     '<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" data-ng-model="mod" is-open="status.opened" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />' +
                     '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                     '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="opened($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </button>' +
                     '</span>' +
                 '</div>',
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    // all the directive code
                    console.log(iAttrs.format); // dd/MM/yyyy
                    console.log(iAttrs.ngModel); //  oneWMS.dateReviewed
                    console.log(iAttrs.status); // statusDateReviewed
                    console.log(iAttrs.opened); // openDateReviewed
                    console.log(iAttrs.modelName); // dateReviewed

                    var modelStatusDate = iAttrs.status;
                    var modelOpenDate = iAttrs.opened;
                    var modelName = iAttrs.modelName;

                    scope.today = function() {
                        scope.modelName = new Date();
                        scope.dateApproved = new Date();
                      scope.today();

                      scope.clear = function () {
                        scope.modelName = null;
                      };

                      scope.modelOpenDate = function($event) {
                        scope.modelStatusDate.opened = true;
                      };

                      scope.modelStatusDate = {
                        opened: false
                      };


                      scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
                        if (mode === 'day') {
                          var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

                          for (var i=0;i<scope.events.length;i++){
                            var currentDay = new Date(scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

                            if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                              return scope.events[i].status;
                            }
                          }
                        }

                        return '';
                      };

                } // link
          } // return
    } // picker
    }
```

Don't know if just opening the picker doesn't work or if the date selecting will fail as well.

Comment: If you're using Angular and Bootstrap, I would strongly encourage you to use [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a custom date directive using angularui date-picker. Have a look, it might be useful to you. Here is plunkr url .   http://plnkr.co/edit/FDigEjyMYm5SVYnQyZGp.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.

Comment: I am glad it helped .

Comment: Tell me @Jigs, how can I save that date as 'yyyy-MM-dd'? I want it to be displayed as 'dd/MM/yyyy' in the picker (which works) but need to save it in the database as 'yyyy-MM-dd'. However on select it appears as eg. '2015-08-30T16:00:00.000Z'

Comment: you can use filter for that.
    `$filter('date')(ng-modelVar, "dd/MM/yyyy");` . 
provide ng-modelVar and it will filter the variable in required format.

Comment: I go `scope.isChanged = function () {
    $filter('date')(attrs.ngModel, "yyyy-MM-dd");` but it doesn't work Also the date becomes one day earlier...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90787/discussion-between-underfrog-and-jigs).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular and Bootstrap, I would strongly encourage you to use [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap).

The other Angular UI libraries are not actively maintained.

Comment: That's the one I'm using